# "Gave me one of the recipes that were/was"?

Tags: grammaticality, subject-verb-agreement

I know this is a common question on the web, but I still wasn't sure about this particular sentence.

> "She gave me one of the recipes that **were/was** in her personal cookbook."

In this sentence, I'm not sure if I should go with were or was because I'm not sure what the main subject is. Should I treat "one" as the subject and go with "was" or should I treat "of the recipes" as a clause and choose "were" to match the subject in the clause?

EDIT: I saw this sentence "This is one of the cars that run on hydrogen" on the web and it said that "run" is correct. Is this a different case from my sentence?

Answer (score 4):

The number of the verb in the relative clause is governed not by the subject of the main clause but by its own subject, *which*. *Which*, in turn, derives its number from its referent, which ***may*** be either *one* or *recipes*.

- If the clause answers the question *which recipes?*, *recipes* is the referent, and the verb  must take the plural number: *the recipes which **were** in her personal cookbook.*
- The verb only is only cast in the singular if it answers the question *which one?*: *one which **was** in her personal cookbook.*

More context might make it clear which of these is intended; but without that context, I think it more likely that the clause modifies *recipes*.

- The relativizer *that* and the absence of a comma demonstrate that the clause is restrictive—that is, it specifies something rather than just adding parenthetical information; so we cannot interpret this as *She gave me one of the recipes, which happened to be one from her personal cookbook.*
- But unlike a non-restrictive clause, which admits some intervening material, a restrictive clause is ordinarily set immediately after its referent. That points to *recipes*.
- Moreover, the presence of the phrase *of the recipes* implies that this is the important specifier for *one*, leaving the relative clause as a specifier of *recipes*. If the author had meant the relative clause to modify *one* it is more likely she would have written  *She gave me **a recipe** that was from her personal cookbook.

We cannot be certain; but I think the balance of probability comes down on the side of *were*:

> She gave me one of the [few, special] recipes which were in her personal cookbook.

Likewise:

> This is one of the [few, special] cars that run on hydrogen.